# PHP Using code as a function, variables not working

Tags: php, function

I've got this code which works well standalone:

```
file_put_contents('dataFile', implode('', 
    array_map(function($data) {
    return stristr($data,"NSQ = ") ? "NSQ = school\n" : $data;
    }, file('dateFile'))
));
```

This reads dataFile and finds the entry `NSQ =` and updates it to be `NSQ = school`

I'm going to reuse this multple times so changed it into a function:

```
function updatesite($site) {
file_put_contents('dataFile', implode('', 
    array_map(function($data) {
    return stristr($data,"$site = ") ? "$site = school\n" : $data;
    }, file('dateFile'))
));
}
```

Initially, I got an error that `$site` didn't exist, so I added `global $site;` before the return.

That stopped the error, but it doesn't update the file.

Is there any way I can use a variable like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `use` to pass variables to a function callback like this:

```
function updatesite($site) {
    file_put_contents('dataFile', implode('', 
        array_map(function($data) use ($site) {
            return stristr($data,"$site = ") ? "$site = school\n" : $data;
        }, file('dateFile'))
    ));
}
```